# Android : how to edit the bar at the top of the screen?

Tags: android

I'm beginning to learn Android Development and I have a bar at the top of my app, containing the title of the activity and the app icon. I want to know how to edit it (change the text, background color, etc), and remove it ? I also want to know how to edit the title of my app, because it's currently the name of its main activity...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_label" 
>
...
    <activity
        android:name="foo.MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_label" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

If you don't want any titlebar, add the attribute:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

To the application tag.

Comment: If I do that, it works for the name of my app, but the bar at the top of it also contains this text and I don't want it.

Comment: I edited, you can also set / remove label attribute for the activity, is that what you mean?

Comment: Something I don't understand : I've put `<application android:label="@string/app_name">` and inside it `<activity android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >`. But the name of my app appearing on the device is also the name of my main activity and not app_name, why ?

Comment: Because the label of the activity overrides the label of the application... and you don't have to give a label to the activity, if you don't use label in the activity, you will see the label of the application.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. So I guess there is no way to do it with XML, I have to code it in my Activity ?

Comment: What exactly you want to do? If you want to change the text, just edit the XML - if you want to do further customizations, you probably are better using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` and using a custom layout for the title bar.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean 'Title Bar' as the bar on the top of the screen, that could be removed by adding the following line to your Manifest

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Add that to the application tag as follows:

```
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know how to edit it (change the text, background color, etc), and remove it ?

If your `android:targetSdkVersion` is API Level 11+, that is called the action bar. You can get an `ActionBar` object by calling `getActionBar()` in your activity (or `getSupportActionBar()` if you are using ActionBarSherlock). There are a series of methods on there for stuff like whether the title is to be displayed or not.

> also want to know how to edit the title of my app, because it's currently the name of its main activity

As lxx notes, your manifest has `android:label` attributes for the `<application>` and `<activity>`, which point to string resources. You can change the values in the string resources to be something else. For activity titles, you can also change them at runtime by calling  `setTitle()` on your `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very complete answer, this.setTitle("Title") in my activity worked perfectly.